# Variable name inside name of another variable

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to do something like htis

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
    $newNode->field_$key['und'][0]['value'] = $value;
    }
```

php complains of Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

I tried

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
    $newNode->field_{$key}['und'][0]['value'] = $value;
    }
```

But then key is output as an array. Not sure why.

Any tips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct notation would be

```
$newNode->{"field_".$key}
```

that should work. But as @Furicane says, arrays are vastly better for this.

Comment: Thanks, this is a winner. I will mark it as such when 4 minutes expired. :)

Answer (score 8):

If I may suggest an alternative approach - which is to use an array. You shouldn't try to dynamically create variable names. For that purpose, good engineers from a long, long time ago in a year far far away invented an array.

So, to solve your problems from now and the whole eternity - rewrite your code to use:

```
$newNode->field[$key]['und'][0]['value'] = $value;
```

Comment: +1 Exactly. Arrays are already in copious use anyway, so adding another dimension wouldn't hurt.

Comment: This is not entirely true, as there are valid use-cases for dynamically accessing properties.  Late static binding makes a host of well-built applications possible in php 5.3.  Don't misconstrue this statement though; usually an array would be appropriate.

Comment: Also, if you are indexing that many things at once, you should probably think about what you are doing and add some classes as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately my hands are tied on this one as I am working with Drupal that uses this notation for fields, here is an example: http://timonweb.com/comment/4751

Answer (score 1):

Try using a variable for the full property name.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $fieldName = "field_{$key}";
    $newNode->{$fieldName}['und'][0]['value'] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Thanbks this is a winner as well. Pekka's solution was posted before this, so I will mark that as correct.

Answer (score 0):

variable name (and also object property) [cannot have $ in name](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).

To get this working, read about [getters and setters with __get and __set](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, will read up on this. Pekka's solution works so I went with that for now.